# How to get the first five images from a list of reviews

Tags: xpath

I need help in getting the first images from a list of reviews. I have to get just the first images from the first five reviewers. And the reviews look something like this.

```
<div class='feedback item'>
    <dl class='buyer-review'>
        <dd class='photo-list'>
            <ul>
                <li> <img> </li>
                <li> <img> </li>
                <li> <img> </li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class='buyer-additional-review'>
        <dd class='photo-list'>
            <ul>
                <li> <img> </li>
                <li> <img> </li>
                <li> <img> </li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Sometimes there is an additional review, and sometimes none. Sometimes, the image can be found in the additional review and not in the main review. The thing that I need to do is get just one image from each reviewer.

I tried doing something like this:
`//div[position()<6]/dl/dd//ul/li[1]/img`
This gets the images from the first five reviewers, but sometimes it returns more than 5 images if there's an image in the main review and in the additional review.

So I tried doing something like this:
`//div[position()<6]/dl[1]/dd//ul/li[1]/img`
But sometimes it returns less than 5 images if the image is located in the additional review and not in the main review.

Essentially, I just need to get one image per reviewer, and it doesn't matter if it's from the main review or from the additional review.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Got this to work for now with this. 
`(//div/dl[1]/dd/ul/li[1]/img)[position()<6]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `//div/dl[position()<6]/dd/ul/li[1]/img`

you have to take position of dl not div as it seems from your xml.

Comment: If I do that, I will get more than 5 images because it will select all the reviewers and all their reviews (main and additional). So I might get 2 images per reviewer and it will select more than five reviewers.

Comment: In that case there needs to be an attribute that specifies the images are from the same buyer or you can combine images into one 'dl', otherwise you need to write xsl.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```css
(//div[position()<6]//img)[1]
//div[position()<6]/dl[.//img][1]//img
```